# GVM installed gradle is not recognized in Linux terminal

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, griffon

Recently installed gradle via gvm and `$ gradle build` throws the following error message.

```
If 'gradle' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this: cnf gradle
```

Obviously, class path issues, So I have tried  `echo $GRADLE_HOME` outputs 
    /home/karthikeyan/.gvm/gradle/current

But the actual binary is at /home/karthikeyan/.gvm/gradle/2.3/bin (exporting this to path variable,works). What if I am switching between the versions? Is there any general solution ?

Comment: Does `gvm` work from the command line? Have you modified you shell conf file e.g. `.zshrc` appropriately?

Comment: @Opal, please find the edited version of the question. Yes gvm works perfect.

Comment: i have added the $GRADLE_HOME\bin to path. No use, path to the actual binary works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *always* use `$GRADLE_HOME` which points to `$HOME/.gvm/gradle/current/`- so if not `$GRADLE_HOME` use the latter path.

If there's a need to switch between versions use the following command:

```
gvm use gradle <version>
```

The `../current/` *path* is a symlink that points the version of gradle being in use. It's done in the following way to ease the usage - just add `../current` *path* to `$PATH` and it's done, instead of switching the versions manually every time new version is installed.